# Problem when play video

Tags: lumia-520

When I play a video with HQ in Lumia 520 it usually buffering alot. Even I try tube pro or other it still buffering while I play a video. I just got that problem 2 days ago

Comment: Are you talking about Youtube videos? Are you on a cellular or WiFi connection? What kind of speeds are you getting? You can use [this handy app](http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=9b9ae06b-2961-41ef-987d-b09567cffe70) to test the speed of your internet connection.

Comment: If you have a separate problem, [please click here to ask a new question](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/8785/106