# How to improve internet speed?

Tags: lumia-520

How can I improve my internet speed if my wifi is too slow to see a video on my Lumia 520? Is there a good app that helps with internet speed? I tried boost but it didn't work so well.

Answer (score 3):

Your internet speed is limited by your WiFi Speed and distance you are from the WiFi source. If your ISP provider gives you slow speed, you can try to upgrade your bandwidth - there is nothing that Windows Phone or your WiFi can do anything here :)